# Can while loop print hour with other while loop?

Tags: python, selenium, automation, bots

I have bot witch is making automation for me using selenium. I have counter, but I need to have date too, my code is:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import time
import datetime

i = 1

    actions = ActionChains(OMS)
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    while i <= amount:

        time.sleep(1)

        bot.find_element_by_class_name('classname').click()
        actions.send_keys("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetlerisque." + Keys.RETURN)
        actions.perform()

        time.sleep(3)

        print(i)
        print(str(now))

        i = i + 1

OMS.description(500)



 **output:**
 [1
 2020 11 9 13 30 9
 [2
 2020 11 9 13 30 9
 [3
 2020 11 9 13 30 9
 [4
 2020 11 9 13 30 9...]
```

Can my code print the date and time of sended keys?

Comment: `amount` is undefined.

Comment: ok, thanks, I forgot to paste that line

Comment: Just put the now inside the loop and it should increment itself. After the click().